# Is there an error in the way this simulation calculates gravitational attraction and body collision?

Tags: javascript, debugging, simulation, physics, physics-engine

N-Body gravity simulation seems to be working fine at first glance, and the same is true for body collisions, but once gravitationally attracted objects start to collide, they start to spiral around each other frantically and the collection of them as a whole have very erratic motion...  The code (html-javascript) will be included below, and to reproduce what I'm talking about, you can create a new body by clicking in a random location on the screen.

The math for gravitational attraction is done in the Body.prototype.gravityCalc() method of the Body object type (line 261).  The math for the collision resolution is found in the dynamic collision section of the bodyHandle() function (line 337).

```js
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// event handling

document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown)
document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp)
document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
document.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart);
document.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove);
document.addEventListener('touchend', touchEnd);
window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
window.onload = function() {reset()}

mouseDown = false;
nothingGrabbed = true;
mouseX = 0;
mouseY = 0;

function keyDown(data) {
    if(data.key == "r") {
        clearInterval(loop);
        reset();
    }
    else if(data.key == 'g') {
        gravityOn = !gravityOn;
    }
    else if(data.key == 'Delete') {
        for(i = 0; i < bodies.length ; i++) {
            if(((mouseX - bodies[i].x)**2 + (mouseY - bodies[i].y)**2) <= bodies[i].radius**2) {
                bodies.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    else if(data.key == 'c') {
        gravity_c *= -1;
    }
    else if(data.key == 'f') {
        falling = !falling;
    }
    else if(data.key == 'a') {
        acceleration *= -1;
    }
}
function mouseDown(data) {
    mouseDown = true;
    nothingGrabbed = true;
    mouseX = data.clientX;
    mouseY = canvas.height - data.clientY;
}
function mouseUp(data) {
    mouseDown = false;
    nothingGrabbed = true;
    for(i = 0; i < bodies.length; i++) {
        bodies[i].grabbed = false
    }
}
function mouseMove(data) {
    mouseX = data.clientX;
    mouseY = canvas.height - data.clientY;
}
function touchStart(data) {
    mouseDown = true;
    nothingGrabbed = true;
    mouseX = data.touches[0].clientX;
    mouseY = canvas.height - data.touches[0].clientY;
}
function touchMove(data) {
    mouseX = data.touches[0].clientX;
    mouseY = canvas.height - data.touches[0].clientY;
}
function touchEnd(data) {
    mouseDown = false;
    nothingGrabbed = true;
    for(i=0;i<bodies.length;i++) {
        bodies[i].grabbed = false;
    }
}
function resize(data) {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Initialize Variables

function reset() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.color = 'rgb(70, 70, 70)';
    
    scale = Math.min(canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    
    fps = 120;
    running = true;
    
    
    loop = setInterval(main, 1000/fps);

    
    gravityOn = true // if true, objects are gravitationally attracted to each other
    gravity_c = 334000 // universe's gravitational constant

    boundaryCollision = true // if true, objects collide with edges of canvas
    wallDampen = 0.7 // number to multiply by when an objects hit a wall

    bodyCollision = true // if true, bodies will collide with each other
    bodyDampen = 0.4 // number to multiply when two objects collide

    falling = false // if true, objects will fall to the bottom of the screen
    acceleration = 400
    
    bodies = [] // a list of each Body object
    collidingPairs = [] // a list of pairs of colliding bodies
    
    /*
    var bounds = 200;
    for(i = 0; i<70; i++) { // randomly place bodies
        Body.create({
            x: Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.width),
            y: Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.height),
            a: Math.random()*Math.PI*2,
            xV: Math.floor(Math.random() * (bounds - -bounds)) + -bounds,
            yV: Math.floor(Math.random() * (bounds - -bounds)) + -bounds,
            mass: Math.ceil(Math.random()*23)
        })
    } */
    
    /*
    Body.create({
        x: canvas.width/2 - 50,
        xV: 10,
        yV: 0,
        aV: 3,
        y: canvas.height/2 + 0,
        mass: 10
    });
    Body.create({
        x: canvas.width/2 + 50,
        xV: 0,
        aV: 0,
        y: canvas.height/2,
        mass: 10
    });
    
    */
    
    
    
    Body.create({
    x: canvas.width/2, 
    y: canvas.height/2, 
    mass: 24, 
    xV: -10.83
    });
    Body.create({
    x: canvas.width/2, 
    y: canvas.height/2 + 150, 
    mass: 1, 
    xV: 260, 
    color: 'teal'
    });
    
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Body Type Object

function Body(params) {
    this.x = params.x || canvas.width/2;
    this.y = params.y || canvas.height/2;
    this.a = params.a || 0;
    
    this.xV = params.xV || 0;
    this.yV = params.yV || 0;
    this.aV = params.aV || 0;
    
    this.xA = params.xA || 0;
    this.yA = params.yA || 0;
    this.aA = params.aA || 0;
    
    this.grabbed = false;
    
    this.edgeBlock = params.edgeBlock || boundaryCollision;
    
    this.gravity = params.gravityOn || gravityOn;
    
    this.mass = params.mass || 6;
    this.density = params.density || 0.008;
    this.radius = params.radius || (this.mass/(Math.PI*this.density))**0.5;
    this.color = params.color || 'crimson';
    this.lineWidth = params.lineWidth || 2;
}

Body.create = function(params) {
    bodies.push(new Body(params));
}

Body.prototype.move = function() {
    this.xV += this.xA/fps;
    this.yV += this.yA/fps;
    this.aV += this.aA/fps;
    this.x += this.xV/fps;
    this.y += this.yV/fps;
    this.a += this.aV/fps;
    
    if(this.edgeBlock) {
        if(this.x + this.radius > canvas.width) {
            this.x = canvas.width - this.radius;
            this.xV *= -wallDampen
        }
        else if(this.x - this.radius < 0) {
            this.x = this.radius;
            this.xV *= -wallDampen;
        }
        if(this.y + this.radius > canvas.height) {
            this.y = canvas.height - this.radius;
            this.yV *= -wallDampen;
        }
        else if(this.y - this.radius < 0) {
            this.y = this.radius;
            this.yV *= -wallDampen;
        }
    }
    if(this.grabbed) {
        this.xA = 0;
        this.yA = 0;
        this.xV = 0;
        this.yV = 0;
        this.x = mouseX;
        this.y = mouseY;
    }
}

Body.prototype.draw = function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
    ctx.fillStyle =  this.color;
    ctx.arc(this.x, canvas.height - this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath()
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.lineWidth = this.linewidth;
    ctx.moveTo(this.x, canvas.height - this.y);
    ctx.lineTo(this.x + this.radius*Math.cos(this.a), canvas.height - (this.y + this.radius*Math.sin(this.a)))
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

// calculates gravitational attraction to 'otherObject'
Body.prototype.gravityCalc = function(otherObject) {
    var x1 = this.x;
    var y1 = this.y;
    var x2 = otherObject.x;
    var y2 = otherObject.y;
    var distSquare = ((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2);
    var val = (gravity_c*otherObject.mass)/((distSquare)**(3/2));
    var xA = val * (x2 - x1);
    var yA = val * (y2 - y1);
    
    return [xA, yA]
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Physics Code

function bodyHandle() {
    for(i = 0; i < bodies.length; i++) {
        
        if(mouseDown && nothingGrabbed) {
            if(Math.abs((mouseX - bodies[i].x)**2 + (mouseY - bodies[i].y)**2) <= bodies[i].radius**2) {
                bodies[i].grabbed = true;
                nothingGrabbed = false;
            }
        }
        
        bodies[i].draw()
        
        if(running) {
            if(falling) {
                bodies[i].yV -= acceleration/fps;
            }
            bodies[i].move();
        }
        
        bodies[i].xA = 0;
        bodies[i].yA = 0;
        collidingPairs = []
        if(gravityOn || bodyCollision) {
            for(b = 0; b < bodies.length; b++) {
                if(i != b) {
                    if(bodyCollision) {
                        var x1 = bodies[i].x;
                        var y1 = bodies[i].y;
                        var x2 = bodies[b].x;
                        var y2 = bodies[b].y;
                        var rSum = bodies[i].radius + bodies[b].radius;
                        var dist = { // vector
                            i: x2 - x1,
                            j: y2 - y1,
                            mag: ((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)**0.5,
                            norm: {
                                i: (x2-x1)/(((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)**0.5),
                                j: (y2-y1)/(((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)**0.5)
                            }
                        }
                        if(dist.mag <= rSum) { // static collision
                            var overlap = rSum - dist.mag;
                            bodies[i].x -= overlap/2 * dist.norm.i;
                            bodies[i].y -= overlap/2 * dist.norm.j;
                            bodies[b].x += overlap/2 * dist.norm.i;
                            bodies[b].y += overlap/2 * dist.norm.j;
                           
                            collidingPairs.push([bodies[i], bodies[b]]);
                        }
                    }
                    if(gravityOn) {
                        if(bodies[i].gravity) {
                            var accel = bodies[i].gravityCalc(bodies[b]);
                            bodies[i].xA += accel[0];
                            bodies[i].yA += accel[1];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for(c = 0; c < collidingPairs.length; c++) { // dynamic collision
            var x1 = collidingPairs[c][0].x;
            var y1 = collidingPairs[c][0].y;
            var r1 = collidingPairs[c][0].radius;
            var x2 = collidingPairs[c][1].x;
            var y2 = collidingPairs[c][1].y;
            var r2 = collidingPairs[c][1].radius;
            var dist = { // vector from b1 to b2
                    i: x2 - x1,
                    j: y2 - y1,
                    mag: ((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)**0.5,
                    norm: {
                        i: (x2-x1)/(((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)**0.5),
                        j: (y2-y1)/(((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)**0.5)
                    }
            }
            var m1 = collidingPairs[c][0].mass;
            var m2 = collidingPairs[c][1].mass;
            
            var norm = { // vector normal along 'wall' of collision
                i: -dist.j/(((dist.i)**2 + (-dist.j)**2)**0.5),
                j: dist.i/(((dist.i)**2 + (-dist.j)**2)**0.5)
            }
            var perp = { // vector normal pointing from b1 to b2
                i: dist.norm.i,
                j: dist.norm.j
            }
            
            var vel1 = { // vector of b1 velocity
                i: collidingPairs[c][0].xV,
                j: collidingPairs[c][0].yV,
                dot: function(vect) {
                    return collidingPairs[c][0].xV * vect.i + collidingPairs[c][0].yV * vect.j
                }
            }
            var vel2 = { // vector of b2 velocity
                i: collidingPairs[c][1].xV,
                j: collidingPairs[c][1].yV,
                dot: function(vect) {
                    return collidingPairs[c][1].xV * vect.i + collidingPairs[c][1].yV * vect.j
                }
            }
            
            // new velocities along perp^ of b1 and b2
            var nV1Perp = (vel1.dot(perp))*(m1-m2)/(m1+m2) + (vel2.dot(perp))*(2*m2)/(m1+m2);
            var nV2Perp = (vel1.dot(perp))*(2*m1)/(m1+m2) + (vel2.dot(perp))*(m2-m1)/(m1+m2);
            
            /* testing rotation after collision
            // velocities of the points of collision on b1 and b2
            var pVel1M = vel1.dot(norm) + collidingPairs[c][0].aV*r1;
            var pVel2M = vel2.dot(norm) + collidingPairs[c][1].aV*r2;
            
            // moment of inertia for b1 and b2
            var I1 = 1/2 * m1 * r1**2;
            var I2 = 1/2 * m2 * r2**2;
            
            // new velocities of the points of collisions on b1 and b2
            var newpVel1M = ((I1-I2)/(I1+I2))*pVel1M + ((2*I2)/(I1+I2))*pVel2M;
            var newpVel2M = ((2*I1)/(I1+I2))*pVel1M + ((I2-I1)/(I1+I2))*pVel2M;
            
            var vectToCol1 = { // vector from x1,y1 to point of collision on b1
                i: r1*perp.i,
                j: r1*perp.j
            };
            var vectToCol2 = { // vector from x2,y2 to point of collision on b2
                i: r2*-perp.i,
                j: r2*-perp.j
            };
            
            // sign of cross product of pVelM and vectToCol
            var vCrossR1 = (pVel1M*norm.i)*(vectToCol1.j) - (pVel1M*norm.j)*(vectToCol1.i);
            vCrossR1 = vCrossR1/Math.abs(vCrossR1);
            var vCrossR2 = (pVel2M*norm.i)*(vectToCol2.j) - (pVel2M*norm.j)*(vectToCol2.i);
            vCrossR2 = vCrossR2/Math.abs(vCrossR2);

            
            collidingPairs[c][0].aV = vCrossR1 * (newpVel1M)/r1;
            collidingPairs[c][1].aV = vCrossR2 * (newpVel2M)/r2;
            
            /* draw collision point velocity vectors [debugging]
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
            ctx.moveTo(x1 + vectToCol1.i, canvas.height - (y1 + vectToCol1.j));
            ctx.lineTo((x1+vectToCol1.i) + pVel1M*norm.i, (canvas.height- (y1+vectToCol1.j + pVel1M*norm.j)));
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
            ctx.moveTo(x2 + vectToCol2.i, canvas.height - (y2 + vectToCol2.j));
            ctx.lineTo((x2+vectToCol2.i) + pVel2M*norm.i, (canvas.height- (y2+vectToCol2.j + pVel2M*norm.j)));
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
            console.log(pVel1M, pVel2M);
            clearInterval(loop);
            */
            
            collidingPairs[c][0].xV = vel1.dot(norm)*norm.i + nV1Perp*perp.i * bodyDampen;
            collidingPairs[c][0].yV = vel1.dot(norm)*norm.j + nV1Perp*perp.j * bodyDampen;
            
            collidingPairs[c][1].xV = vel2.dot(norm)*norm.i + nV2Perp*perp.i * bodyDampen;
            collidingPairs[c][1].yV = vel2.dot(norm)*norm.j + nV2Perp*perp.j * bodyDampen;
        }
        
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Main Loop

function main() {
    // blank out canvas
    ctx.fillStyle = canvas.color;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    bodyHandle();
    if(nothingGrabbed && mouseDown) {
        bodies.push(new Body({x: mouseX, 
            y: mouseY, 
            mass: 90}));
        bodies[bodies.length-1].move();
        bodies[bodies.length-1].draw();
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,height=device-height'>

<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width='300px' height='300px'></canvas>
<style>
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
canvas {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
</style>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems that the system is gaining a significant amount of energy every time the moon orbits the planet at surface level (and if it weren't for the restitution coefficient of the walls would reach escape velocity very quickly), probably due to Euler integration.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell you much about the code. Personally it seems to me that the animations could be correct.

**If you want to test your code you could try to test if laws of conservation of energy and momentum are respected**. You could, for example, ***sum the momentum of every object (mass times velocity) and see if the number are maintained constant when there are no forces from the outside*** (collisions with the wall). To do this I would suggest to make the free space available larger. Another quantity is the total energy (kinetic plus potential) which is a bit harder, but still easy to compute (to compute tot. pot. energy you have to sum over all pairs).